# Will my help to the poor still be accepted by Allah?

Tags: sadaqah

Suppose I give some monetary help to a distressed poor man thinking that may Allah also help my parents and myself.

Some days later I discover that the poor man was actually a cheat who cheats people to gather money for his livelihood. But, for the shake of avoiding any further trouble I let the man go.

Will I still be a candidate for Allah's help?

Please supply me with some quotes from Quran and hadith.

Comment: You gave with good intentions, while he received it with ill-intentions. So to each his intention. Know that more important than the sadaqah is the intention behind it. Allah validates His servants acts by their intentions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, inshallah.

In Islam, the concept of intentions overruling anything else is a recurring theme. If you commit a crime unknowingly (therefore, without the intention of doing so), you are with the mercy of Allah SWT forgiven. If you commit an act with the intention of it being a "good deed" then regardless of the outcome, your *ajr* is with Allah SWT.

> إنَّمَا الأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّياَّتِ وَإنمَّاَ لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى،
>   فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى اللهِ وَرَسُولِهِ فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى
>   اللهِ وَرَسُولِهِ، وَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ لِدُنْياَ يُصِيْبُهَا
>   أَوِ امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْه
>
> رَوَاهُ البُخَارِيُّ وَمُسْلِمٌ

And the translation:

> It is narrated on the authority of Amirul Mu'minin, Abu Hafs 'Umar bin
>   al-Khattab, radiyallahu 'anhu, who said: I heard the Messenger of
>   Allah, sallallahu 'alayhi wasallam, say:
>
> "Actions are (judged) by motives (niyyah), so each man will have what
>   he intended. Thus, he whose migration (hijrah) was to Allah and His
>   Messenger, his migration is to Allah and His Messenger; but he whose
>   migration was for some worldly thing he might gain, or for a wife he
>   might marry, his migration is to that for which he migrated."

If your intention was indeed to help a poor man for the sake of Allah SWT and for His sake alone, then that is how, inshallah, you will be rewarded; regardless of the true identity of the "pauper" you helped.

Wallahu a'lam.